# No graphs are being displayed in APC.php file

Tags: apc

I'm using APC with W3 Total Cache on my WordPress website. Today I had to upgrade to a bigger VPS server. The host said everything went fine and everything is actually working like before.

However the APC.php file isn't showing the graphs anymore. It still shows all the statistics, etc... but not the graphs. Any idea what could be causing this?

Thank you.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA717.png

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution. Due to the migration, GD needed to be installed again apparently. Installing GD and rebuilding EasyApache fixed it.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue, but don't know what GD is?

Comment: @iss42 `apt-get install php5-gd`